# Can I make iTunes stop asking to access my phone?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I plug my phone (iPhone 5s, though I doubt it matters) into my laptop at work in order to charge it. Every time I do, if iTunes is open (it usually is, because music), it pops up a dialog to ask if I want to allow iTunes to access information on the phone.

I don't, and I'm getting tired of clicking through the dialog every time. Is there a way to get it to stop asking, either for this specific device, or in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a "charge only" or "data block" lightning cable.

One example: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01F7AU62E/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_FZmiAbB2FJDDE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01F7AU62E)

These cables only let power thru, data is blocked or not connected.